# changing link's onclick event and text from child window

Tags: javascript, popup, hyperlink

I have a link on my parent page. When i click on it a popup opens. On the popup I have a button, when I click on it I need to change link's which is on the parent window(clicked to open popup), text and onClick event.

How can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its better to reference a function on the parent window, rather than write code on the popup, so I'd use  parent.some_function();

This way, if the original page changes, you can change the function there too, without searching through your popup windows.

Comment: I assume this is a popup and not a separate window or tab, as loler suggests.

Answer (score 0):

You can not access tab/window elements from different tab/window.

Comment: Your answer that "you can't do it" would be more helpful if you offered a suggestion as to another approach...